General conditions for meromorphic continuation of a Dirichlet series
I've read many posts on this site as well as on MathOverflow that suggest that Dirichlet series admit meromorphic continuations only in very special conditions. But I just stumbled across the paper  https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-120-02/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7/S0002-9939-1994-1172954-7.pdf, which gives Euler's elementary proof of the meromorphic continuation of the $\zeta$-function, and it seems like the argument generalizes to any Dirichlet series $L(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n/n^s$, so long as $|a_n| = n^{o(1)}$ and $a_{2n} = a_2a_n$. (This multiplicativity condition can be relaxed in many cases of interest; for example, if $L(s)$ admits an Euler product expansion, we can adjust the Euler product by removing the factor at $p = 2$.) So this is my question:
Question: Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $a_{2n} = a_2a_n$ and $|a_n| = n^{o(1)}$. Then does the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n/n^s$ admit a meromorphic continuation to all of $\mathbb{C}$, with at most a simple pole?
I can't seem to find the mistake in the following proof attempt; I feel like it cannot possibly be correct because it suggests that a seemingly large class of Dirichlet series admit meromorphic continuation to all of $\mathbb{C}$.
Proof attempt: Observe that the Dirichlet series for $L(s)$ converges for all $s$ with $\Re(s) > 1$. Using the multiplicativity property $a_{2n} = a_2a_n$, we find that
\begin{equation} \label{eq-thedouble}
\big(1 - a_2 2^{1-s}\big)L(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{a_n}{n^s}.
\end{equation}
Applying Euler's transformation of series to the right-hand side, we find
\begin{equation} \label{eq-combo}
    \big(1 - a_2 2^{1-s}\big)L(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{m = 0}^n (-1)^m {n \choose m} \frac{a_{m+1}}{(m+1)^s}.
\end{equation}
We claim that the series on the right-hand side converges absolutely and uniformly on compact sets to an entire function. For each integer $k \geq 0$ and complex number $s = \sigma + it$, we have
\begin{align} \label{eq-rewriteinnersum}
\left|\sum_{m = 0}^k (-1)^m {k \choose m} \frac{a_{m+n}}{(m+n)^s}\right| & \ll (n+k)^{o(1)} \times \left|\bigg(\prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (s+i)\bigg) \times \int_{\vec{x} \in [0,1]^k} \bigg(n + \sum_{i = 1}^k x_i\bigg)^{-s-k} d\vec{x}\right| \\
& \ll \phi(s,k,n) :=\frac{(n+k)^{o(1)}}{n^{\sigma+k}}\left|\prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (s+i)\right| \nonumber
\end{align}
where the implied constants are absolute. Now let $S$ be a compact set in the half-plane defined by $\sigma > 1-k$, and let $M_n := \max_{s \in S} \phi(s,k,n)$. Then the bound above implies that for all $s \in S$, the sum $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty M_n$ dominates the series
\begin{equation} \label{eq-interseries}
    \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{m = 0}^k (-1)^m {k \choose m} \frac{a_{m+n}}{(m+n)^s}.
\end{equation}
By the triangle inequality, the Euler transformation of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty M_n$ also dominates the Euler transformation of the above series, which transform is readily seen to be
\begin{equation} \label{eq-eulertransform}
    \sum_{n = k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1-k}} \sum_{m = 0}^n (-1)^m {n \choose m} \frac{a_{m+1}}{(m+1)^s}.
\end{equation}
Multiplying this by $2^{-k}$ and extending the range of summation to all integers $n \geq 0$ yields the series expansion of $(1-a_22^{1-s})L(s)$, the convergence of which now follows from that of the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty M_n$.
